# How can we turn automatic brightness off in android?

Tags: android

How can we turn automatic brightness off in android?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
```

Comment: thanx Dusty to get idea i have done like this
  Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
       Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL); and got right result

Comment: No problem.  You may want to accept the answer so anyone running across it will know it's been answered and not have click to see.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: Which package should be imported for this `Settings` and `SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE`?

Comment: @Deqing, Settings is a default android library. Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html