# How do you set brightness of screen in Android?

Tags: android, screen-brightness

I want a dialog that adjusts brightness of the screen using `SeekBar`.

How to display custom dialog with `SeekBar` that adjusts brightness of screen?

Comment: You can't adjust the screen brightness anymore at a global level; note this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158628/android-short-screen-brightness-code

Comment: yeah.. it will apply only to your window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can use this API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness). This will change screen brightness of your window and not of the whole system.

```
        // Make the screen full bright for this activity.
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = 1.0f;

        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Answer (score 2):

This [code snippet](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/07/reducing-dimness-while-running-progress.html) should help you

```
pdlg = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Loading...", ""); 
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = pdlg.getWindow().getAttributes();
p.dimAmount=0.0f;        //Dim Amount
pdlg.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  //Applying properties to progress dialog
pdlg.dismiss(); //Dismiss the dialog
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can set the system brightness like this:

```
 //Set the system brightness using the brightness variable value
System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
//Get the current window attributes
LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
//Set the brightness of this window
layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float)255;
//Apply attribute changes to this window
window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
```

Or you may refer on this complete [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/09/change-screen-brightness.html)